# Inserting null in a Java vector

Tags: java, vector, insert, null

I am trying to insert the contents of a .txt file to a vector using tokenizer; but a specific file doesnt get inserted.Also later i need to pass the contents of vector to a jtable later.The problem is first line of .txt has null value so it doesnt get inserted it skips the first line and moves on.. is there a way to store null in vector and replace it with " " ?

```
private void loadSecondPreview() {
  String aLine;
  recordData = new Vector();
  columnNames = new Vector();

  try {
    FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(dataFile);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fin));
    // extract column names
    if (delimiter == ",") {
      StringTokenizer st1 =
        new StringTokenizer(br.readLine(), ",");
      while (st1.hasMoreTokens()) {
        columnNames.addElement(st1.nextToken());
    }
    // extract data
    while ((aLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
      StringTokenizer st2 =
        new StringTokenizer(aLine, ",");
      while (st2.hasMoreTokens()) {
        recordData.addElement(st2.nextToken());
      }
    }
  } else if (delimiter == "\t") {
    StringTokenizer st1 =
      new StringTokenizer(br.readLine(), "\t");
    while (st1.hasMoreTokens()) {
      if (st1.equals(null)) {
        columnNames.addElement(" ");
      } else {
        columnNames.addElement(st1.nextToken());
      }
    }
    // extract data
    while ((aLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
      StringTokenizer st2 =
        new StringTokenizer(aLine, "\t");
      while (st2.hasMoreTokens()) {
        if (st2.equals(null)) {
          recordData.addElement(" ");
        } else {
          recordData.addElement(st2.nextToken());
        }
      }
    }
  }
  br.close();

  System.out.println("Column vector size:" + columnNames.size());
  System.out.println("Record vector size:" + recordData.size());

  for (int x = 0; x < columnNames.size(); x++) {
    System.out.println("Column vector:" + x + " " + columnNames.elementAt(x));
  }

  for (int x = 0; x < recordData.size(); x++) {
    System.out.println("Record vector:" + x + " " + recordData.elementAt(x));
  }
```

O/P: 
**Column vector size:0
Record vector size:5
Record vector:0 8
Record vector:1 8.100
Record vector:2 8.200
Record vector:3 9
Record vector:4 9.8

test file records:first line has two null value columns

8   8.100
    8.200
9   9.8

Comment: Can't you just check for nulll before inserting, and if null insert a blank value instead?

Answer (score 2):

Try This

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(loc + fname));
    ArrayList<String []> input = new ArrayList<String []>();
    String [] temp;
    String line;
    String stemp = null, sprev;
    ArrayList<String> comp = new ArrayList<String>();
    while((line = in.readLine())!= null)
    {
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line, ",", true);
        temp = new String [15];
        int i = 0;
        while(st.hasMoreTokens())
        {
            sprev = stemp;
            stemp = st.nextToken(); 
            if((stemp.equals(sprev)) && stemp.equals(","))                
            {
                //it is a null field
                temp[i++] = null;                    
            }
            else if(!(stemp.equals(",")))
            {
                temp[i++] = stemp;
            }
        }
        input.add(temp);
```

Works for me

Answer (score 1):

something like this:

```
add(value == null ? "" : value)
```

Comment: So i think the problem is with StringTokenizer; i did replace my code with  columnNames.addElement( st1.nextToken()== null ? "" : st1.nextToken());  is it the right way?

Comment: yes, that's what I ment; if the problem is still there it indeed is something else

Comment: anyway; it would be better to use a List (an ArrayList for example); Vector is an old class that you shouldn't use in new code.

Comment: it would also help us, if you included the stacktrace you are getting

Comment: Do **not** use `st1.nextToken() == null` because this will discard the next token. Store it in a variable, then test and add. Re-read the iterator pattern, what happens when you call `next`. Don't call it twice when you mean to call it just once!

Answer (score 0):

Why you want to use Vector? Consider List as it will maintain the order. 
There are multiple ways to replace blank string in place of null. If you are going to add object from only one place in your code than what mentioned by *Tom* will work. If there are multiple places, than even extending the Vector and overriding add or having convenience method will minimize the check at one place

Comment: `Vector` also maintains the order. As a matter of fact, `Vector` implements `List` and extends `AbstractList`.

Answer (score 0):

The following line in your code

```
if (st1.equals(null)) {
```

does not make any sense. You are testing whether your tokenizer exists, not whether it will return a next token.

Use this pattern:

```
String nextToken = tokenizer.nextToken()
if (nextToken != null) {
    ....
}
```

**DO** use the variable. Because `if (tokenizer.nextToken() == null) { vec.add(tokenizer.nextToken()); }` will use **TWO** tokens. One for testing, one for adding, making the whole test pointless and broken.

It will not be faster just because it is shorter. Beginner error, trying to optimize code by writing less.